# RDP RemoteApp with virtual drive - subst command not honored

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2019, remoteapp

We have set up a RemoteApp with Windows Server 2019 which works fine. However when a app is opened through RemoteApp which has access to the remote computers file system a problem emerges: Virtual drives which are set through the Windows `subst` command are not reachable.

The virtual drives work however if the user logs in through a "classic" RDP session.